# add search criteria PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, search

I have some code which display's products from a MySQL database. The products shown match a search the user has entered.

Here is my code:

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory  = '$catagory' ")
```

In the database i also have a column called `active`, How do i only show reults that match the search criteria (catagory) and have a `1` in the the `active` box?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE catagory  = '$catagory' AND active = '1' ")
```

Make sure you are escaping the `$category` variable before using it in your query to prevent mysql injection exploits and please consider upgrading to a modern database api such as mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @Shane If this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted using the checkmark to the left.